# how to access system files such as network libraries?

Tags: macos, network

I am trying to find some algorithms about the implementation of network stack for Mac OS X, can I access the actual codes from the operating system itself.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has published quite a lot of source code

- [Open Source](http://opensource.apple.com): Source code for a lot of frameworks and commands
- [Open Source Development Resources](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/)

PS: Any detailled discussion about the code (or even where to find which functionality) is off topic on AskDifferent and should be discussed on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was not even sure that I am asking in the right place. Anyway, thanks again.. cheers!